# Putting Data In a DataFrame Gives Different Results in SciKit Learn Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I just noticed that Sci-Kit Learn's Linear Regression algorithm gives some different results are loaded into a pandas dataframe, as opposed to just using them in their raw state.

I don't see why this would be the case.

Consider the following Linear Regression Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
boston     = load_boston()
X1         = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
X1.columns = boston.feature_names
X2         = boston.data
y2         = boston.target
y1         = boston.target
lreg       = LinearRegression()
X1         = (X1 - X1.mean()) / X1.std()
X2         = (X2 - X2.mean()) / X2.std()
```

The resulting models give the same values for R^2 and predictions, but vastly different results for the coefficients and intercepts.

To demonstrate:

```
intcpt1 = lreg.fit(X1, y1).intercept_
intcpt2 = lreg.fit(X2, y2).intercept_
f"Intercept for model with dataframe: {intcpt1}, model with numpy array: {intcpt2}"
```

Gives:

```
'Intercept for model with dataframe: 22.53280632411069, model with numpay array: -941.8009906279219'
```

Likewise, the coefficients are very different:

```
coef1 = lreg.fit(X1, y1).coef_[:3]
coef2 = lreg.fit(X2, y2).coef_[:3]
f"First the coeffs for model with dataframe: {coef1}, modely with numpy array: {coef2}"
```

which gives:

```
'First the coeffs for model with dataframe: [-0.92906457  1.08263896  0.14103943], modely with numpy array: [-15.67844685   6.73818665   2.98419849]'
```

But the score and predictions are the same:

```
score1 = lreg.fit(X1, y1).score(X1, y1)
score2 = lreg.fit(X2, y2).score(X2, y2)
f"Score for model with dataframe: {score1}, model with numpy array: {score2}"
```

Yielding:

```
'Score for model with dataframe: 0.7406426641094094, model with numpy array: 0.7406426641094073'
```

Likewise for coefficients:

```
pred1 = lreg.fit(X1, y1).predict(X1)[:3]
pred2 = lreg.fit(X2, y2).predict(X2)[:3]
f"First 3 predictions with dataframe: {pred1}, with numpy array: {pred2}"
```

Providing:

```
'First 3 predictions with dataframe: [30.00384338 25.02556238 30.56759672], with numpy array: [30.00384338 25.02556238 30.56759672]'
```

`boston.data` is formatted like this:

```
array([[6.3200e-03, 1.8000e+01, 2.3100e+00, ..., 1.5300e+01, 3.9690e+02,
    4.9800e+00],
   [2.7310e-02, 0.0000e+00, 7.0700e+00, ..., 1.7800e+01, 3.9690e+02,
    9.1400e+00],
   [2.7290e-02, 0.0000e+00, 7.0700e+00, ..., 1.7800e+01, 3.9283e+02,
    4.0300e+00],
   ...,
   [6.0760e-02, 0.0000e+00, 1.1930e+01, ..., 2.1000e+01, 3.9690e+02,
    5.6400e+00],
   [1.0959e-01, 0.0000e+00, 1.1930e+01, ..., 2.1000e+01, 3.9345e+02,
    6.4800e+00],
   [4.7410e-02, 0.0000e+00, 1.1930e+01, ..., 2.1000e+01, 3.9690e+02,
    7.8800e+00]])
```

Whereas the dataframe outputs the data like this:

```
     CRIM        ZN     INDUS      CHAS       NOX        RM       AGE  \
0   -0.419367  0.284548 -1.286636 -0.272329 -0.144075  0.413263 -0.119895   
1   -0.416927 -0.487240 -0.592794 -0.272329 -0.739530  0.194082  0.366803   
2   -0.416929 -0.487240 -0.592794 -0.272329 -0.739530  1.281446 -0.265549   
3   -0.416338 -0.487240 -1.305586 -0.272329 -0.834458  1.015298 -0.809088   
4   -0.412074 -0.487240 -1.305586 -0.272329 -0.834458  1.227362 -0.510674   
5   -0.416631 -0.487240 -1.305586 -0.272329 -0.834458  0.206892 -0.350810
```

I'm not clear why the `LinearRegression` algorithm would interpret the info differently in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your transformations:

```
X1 = (X1 - X1.mean()) / X1.std()
X2 = (X2 - X2.mean()) / X2.std()
```

Pandas will calculate the mean and std along the columns. To do it for numpy, add the axis argument to `mean` and `std`:

```
X2 = (X2 - X2.mean(axis=0)) / X2.std(axis=0)
```

Comment: Good catch, but shouldn't that be `axis=1` to operate on the columns?

Comment: Or, better yet, OP could use one of the many scaling or normalizing methods available [within the sklearn framework](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)

Comment: @G.Anderson That's what I thought at first but when I was experimenting, I found that the axis parameter specifies the axis that we are collapsing. There's a post that explains it [here](https://medium.com/@aerinykim/numpy-sum-axis-intuition-6eb94926a5d1).

Comment: Ugh, that one gets me every time! Cheerfully withdrawn!

Comment: @G.Anderson Not the first time for me either!